# On hover an <li> the inner <ul> must slide the next <li>

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

ok, first, what i need to obtain,

[image]

The years 2011,2010,showreels where not visible until you hover PORTFOLIO (but in an iphone its when you first click, but that doesn't matter now)

now, the HTML; just a simple UL with sub UL's

```
<div id="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                                    <ul class="left">
                                        <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">2010</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">SHOWREELS</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>
                                    <ul class="left">
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="/img/westlich.png" alt="Westlich-t" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="/img/sudlich_pink.png" alt="Sudlich-t" /></a></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="/img/sudlich_orange.png" alt="Sudlich-t" /></a></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>                


</ul>
                </div>
```

now, the CSS

```
#nav ul{

}
/*Elemento del men� de navegaci�n, ejemplo: kontact*/

#nav ul li{
    float:left; clear:both; height:40px;
}
#nav ul li a{ color:#000;background:#fff;width:auto;padding: 10px;margin-bottom: 4px; font-weight:bold;}
#nav ul li ul{
     width:100%;
     display:block;
     float:left;
     clear:both;
     z-index:100;
     margin-bottom:100px;
}

/*Sublista del men� de navegacion, de la izda; por ejemplo, portfolio*/
#nav ul li ul.left{
    float:left;

}
/*Sublista del men� de navegacion, de la izda; como Locations*/

#nav ul li ul li{
    width:100%;
}
#nav ul li ul li a{
    width:auto;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

now, the Javascript; making the sub UL visible when the parent LI is hover

```
function menu_desplegable(){
$("#nav ul li ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
$("#nav ul li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);

        },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  menu_desplegable();
});
```

as you can  [test here](http://piscolabis.info/licht) the dropdown effect works, but it doesn't move next `<li>`; for example if you hover porfolio you can see the sublist underneath the rest of the `<li>`'s and I need them to move,

how can i Solve this? I guess i can fix it with only CSS but i'm very lost. Specially because it doesn't even respect the higher z-index :S

Comment: In case I didn't express myself, maybe what i'm looking for is an accordeon effect ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 4 things:

Use `.show()` and `.hide()` instead of `.css({visibility: "hidden"})`.  The latter will hide the element but reserve space for it on the page, resulting in whitespace.  You want `.show()` and `.hide()` because these use `display: none` which hides the element and removes the space it takes up on the page.

Remove this style declaration:

```
#nav ul li
{
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

Remove the bottom margin style definition from the subnav ul (`#nav ul li ul`).

Add `display: inline-block;` to `#nav ul li a`.

That fixes it:  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/3QffD/2/

But you could really clean up your css a lot (looking at the css from your link).  Most of those styles are unnecessary and only make debugging harder.  In particular I see a lot of `float`, `clear`, and `width: 100%` that are unnecessary or even detrimental.  Try to avoid those unless you are sure you need to.

Here's my version with most of the css removed: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/3QffD/

Comment: that's great! but the problem is that as the <li> uses all width i can only hide the sublist vertically... :( any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Toni - It's not clear to me what the problem is you are trying to solve.  In your jsfiddle, it would be impossible to click the links in the sublist.  You say you don't want to hide the sublist vertically.  Does that mean you want the sublist to appear to the right of the main list? You can accomplish that with absolute positioning.  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/3QffD/4/.  Also, you can do all of this without any JavaScript at all by using `:hover` in your css: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/3QffD/5/

Comment: No no, the effect it's perfect; the problem is that <li> is wider than the <a>, so if i put the mouse on the right to the <li> but without hoverint the <a>, the sublist is shown; but if  you check the 'new' JS you should see the difference. If i didn't express myself please hover the green scheppes (background image) you will see what i mean. Also i know i didn't really need JS to archive my question but this was my original goal http://jsfiddle.net/8Ltws/ Don't worrie it's all good know :) Thanks for  your help you really did save me time :)

Answer (score 2):

You are restricting your height on #nav ul li which is preventing it from growing. I'll paste a jsfiddle in a second.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually achievable without Javascript by simply using the :hover selector in CSS. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/7d7sr/

However, the real cause of your problem is this bit of your CSS:

```
#nav ul li{
    float:left; clear:both; height:40px;
}
```

By giving the li a fixed height of 40px, the page doesn't move the following li tags down when you hover over it, because it is still considering them to be 40px. So, instead of making your `#nav ul li {height:40px}`, apply that 40px to the height of the anchor tag it contains: `#nav ul li a {height:40px}`. This will allow the height of the containing li to expand when it's child ul is shown.